# How to stop the user from change the size of the form

Tags: forms, delphi

I have created my project to fir in a portion of the form. I disabled the buttons on the top right hand side of the form(I apologize as I don't know its technical name). I would like to also disable the user from adjust the from size via the cursor. Is that possible through code in delphi?

Comment: Please consider the discussion in comments under my answer. Of course I'm grateful for the "Correct answer" tick mark, but Andreas's answer would deserve it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the form's `BorderStyle` property to `bsSingle`; if it isn't a dynamically generated form, you can do this using the Object Inspector. Also, I understand that you have already removed `biMaximize` from `BorderIcons` (hence, you have removed the Maximize *title bar button*).

I assume now that this is the main form of your application. If, on the other hand, it is a dialog box displayed when you invoke a menu item (for instance), you should instead set `BorderStyle` to `bsDialog`. Such forms are also not resizable, and they have no maximize or minimize title bar buttons).

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

1. Set the form's `BorderIcons.biMinimize = false` and `BorderIcons.biMaximize = false`. (As I think you already have)
2. Assign an event handler for the form's event `OnCanResize`, and code it as follows:

.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCanResize(Sender: TObject; var NewWidth,
  NewHeight: Integer; var Resize: Boolean);
begin
  Resize := False;
end;
```

This prevents the user from resizing the form with the mouse, while the form still has the appearance of a normal form.

Comment: Setting `BorderStyle = bsSingle` will not affect the visual appearance of the form: it will look exactly like a `bsSizeable` form. So far your solution and my are identical. However, with your solution you will still get the sizing cursors when the cursor is hovering the form's border, which you don't get with my `bsSingle` solution. That's why I prefer my solution.

Comment: Difference in visual appearance depends on OS version. In Windows 10 I don't see a difference, you are right.

Comment: What Windows version produces a visible difference?

Comment: Anyhow, at the Win32 API level, the difference between `bsSingle` and `bsSizeable` is that the former uses `WS_BORDER`, while the latter uses `WS_THICKFRAME`, which is the same as  `WS_SIZEBOX`.  The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) says that this style gives the window "a sizing border". So the intension is that such a window is resizeable. Hence, you tell Windows that you want a resizeable window, and then every time Windows asks if the window can be resized, you reply "No". It just doesn't feel quite right to me.

Comment: Ooops! I'm sorry Andreas, I drew the wrong conclusion based on failing memory and the fact that the window border changes in the IDE. I tested on my Win 10 machine and saw the Win 10 single pixel border in both cases, OK. For Win 7 I recalled that the borders were different, but now that I fired up my Win 7 machine, I see that there's also no difference.

Comment: No problem! :) I almost suspected as much.